# How to disable hibernating?

Tags: encryption, hibernate, system

Whereas many questions are geared towards implementing hibernation, mine is how to disable it.

I've just encrypted my swap partition, and I such my system can still hibernate, but cannot resume anymore. So, to avoid mistakes I would to disable hibernating system-wide.

Note: I still want suspend!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this:

```
sudoedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

Change `action id="org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate">defaults>allow_active` to `no`. Save and exit. That will stop users being able to do that from the desktop.

If you have a sleep or hibernate button on your keyboard or case, these will still work IIRC so you need to "break" their default behaviour. Run:

```
gconftool -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/hibernate -t string interactive
```

[Source](http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/disable-suspend-and-hibernate-ubuntu/).

Comment: Will this also stop the machine hibernating when the battery's low?

Comment: @poolie It shouldn't interfere with that (we're not actually breaking the hibernate function)... But I don't know how that event is wired. It might break if it does silly checks.

Comment: @Oli What version of Ubuntu is this for? I did this a few days ago and my computer still sleeps or hibernates every night. It's driving me nuts.