# How can I disable Hibernate completely in Kubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, encryption, hibernate, kubuntu

I have seen the answer on [How to disable hibernating?](https://askubuntu.com/q/12760/6969), but I have no such file. Possibly because that suggestion was written for Ubuntu, not **Kubuntu** (KDE, not Gnome).

I **do not have a swap** on my encrypted SSD, my system freezes (cannot even change Caps Lock) if I accidentally press the "Hibernate" button at "Energy management". My keyboard has a Hibernate button (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>) next to the volume control buttons and every time I press the wrong key, the system will freeze after.

So, what is the correct way to disable it? If there is no solution, a work-around is welcome too.

Comment: +1 This (and disabling suspend) is a very important question for anyone running OCZ Vertex2 drives... suspend/hibernate can instantly obliterate the drive with no hope of recovering a single byte. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Triggers for hibernation:

- Press the Hibernate button in Kickoff -> Leave -> Hibernate
- Press Hibernate on the Energy icon in the system tray
- Send a dbus signal: `qdbus org.kde.kded /modules/powerdevil suspend 4`

When hibernation is triggered, this is the execution flow:

1. `/usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-hibernate-linux` is called
2. `/usr/sbin/pm-hibernate` is called with some arguments
3. Logging starts to `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`
4. Hooks are executed to prepare for hibernation. These hooks are located at `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, and sorted by name (numbers first)
5. `performing hibernate` is written to the log
6. The shell function `do_hibernate` is called, instructing the system to hibernate
7. When the system resumes, hooks are executed to restore from hibernation
8. The system is running again

To disable hibernation, create `/etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernation` with the next content:

```
#!/bin/sh
# prevents hibernation
. "$PM_FUNCTIONS"
[ "$1" = "hibernate" ] && inhibit || true
```

As `000no-hibernation` is called before scripts like `00logging` (outputs modules and memory info in the log), no applications or modules are interrupted or unloaded. This name was inspired by `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change`. Beware of [bug #665651](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/665651) which makes non-zero return values of hooks fail to cancel suspend or hibernation.

This fixes the hibernation issue for me. Although the screen gets locked, I can live with this. It's much better compared to a crashing system.

Comment: I've added `|| true` to prevent a non-zero exitcode, which prevents suspending. Tested to work for suspend and blocking hibernate.

Comment: Great answer!  Very thorough.. Thanks for posting what you found.  Extending on it, [this script](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/58100042/00_avoid_suspend) (from the bug report you linked) cleanly stops both hibernate *and* suspend.  Editing to do just one of them is also trivial.